# Solr - search multiple languages returning duplicates

Tags: search, drupal, solr

I want to search across multiple languages (translations), but when I do duplicate results are returned for each language. I am using Drupal with Search API Solr for the indexing. The results look like the following:

```
[results] => Array
        (
            [3239/en] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3239/en
                    [score] => 1
                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                            [search_api_id] => 3239/en
                            [search_api_relevance] => 1
                        )

                )

            [3240/en] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3240/en
                    [score] => 1
                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                            [search_api_id] => 3240/en
                            [search_api_relevance] => 1
                        )

                )
```

So the id and language are both contained in the key/id. Currently I can filter by a language using the code:

```
$index = search_api_index_load('default_multilingual_node_index');
$query = $index->query();
$query->keys($search_terms);

$filter = $query->createFilter('OR');
$filter->condition('search_api_language', $language);
$query->filter($filter);

$results = $query->execute();
```

I have been looking for a way (either Solr config, or Drupal Search API call) to be able to search across multiple languages without the duplicates to no avail. Are there any solutions?

Comment: helpful link https://www.drupal.org/node/2336757

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the below modules

https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_multilingual (for drupal 7)
https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr_multilingual (for drupal 8)

Better support for non-English languages and support for multilingual search